# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable - When using an argument

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I get a `Task not serializable` error when attempting to use an input parameter in a `map`:

```
val errors = inputRDD.map { 
    case (itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector, rating) =>
    (itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector, rating, 
        (
            (rating - userVector.dot(itemVector)) * itemVector) 
            - h4 * userVector
        )
    }
```

I pass `h4` in with the arguments for the Class.

The `map` is in a method and it works fine if before the `map` transformation I put:

```
val h4 = h4
```

If I don't do this, or put this outside the method then it doesn't work and I get `Task not serialisable`. Why is this occurring? Other `val`'s I generate for the Class outside the method work within the method, so how come when the `val` is instantiated from an input parameter/argument it does not?

Comment: `h4` is a variable declared in a separate class? If yes, then try extending that class from Serializable interface.

Comment: what type is h4?  is it serializable?

Comment: `h4` is declared in the Class and is a Double

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the class to which `h4` belongs is not Serializable.

Here is a similar example:

```
class ABC(h: Int) { 
  def test(s:SparkContext) = s.parallelize(0 to 5).filter(_ > h).collect 
}

new ABC(3).test(sc)
//org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
//    Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: 
//    $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$ABC
```

When `this.h` is used in a rdd-transformation, `this` becomes part of the closure which gets serialized.

Making the class Serializable works as expected:

```
class ABC(h: Int) extends Serializable { 
  def test(s:SparkContext) = s.parallelize(0 to 5).filter(_ > h).collect
}

new ABC(3).test(sc)
// Array[Int] = Array(4, 5)
```

So does removing reference to `this` in the rdd-transformation, by defining a local variable in the method:

```
class ABC(h: Int) { 
  def test(s:SparkContext) = { 
      val x = h;
      s.parallelize(0 to 5).filter(_ > x).collect 
  }
}

new ABC(3).test(sc)
// Array[Int] = Array(4, 5)
```

Comment: I was under the impression that a `Double` is serializable? `h4` is a `Double`. Any more thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: @monster yes, Double is serializable, `h4` is a double. The point is: it is a member of a class, so `h4` is shortform of `this.h4`, where `this` refers to the object of the class. When `this.h4 ` is used `this` is pulled into the closure which gets serialized, hence the need to make the class Serializable.

Comment: My class `extends Serializable`; and, it's all in the one Class. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @monster `val errors` and `h4` are members of the same class (which `extends Serializable`?

Comment: @monster In that case, it is possible that the class contains some other member(s) which is not serializable.

Comment: Thanks, this would make sense - as I keep getting the same error - always in this class. I'll try debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can use Broadcast variable. Its Broadcast data from your variable to all your workers. For more Detail visit this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables).